# Как найти, из какого файла индексируется owl-carousel?

Tags: веб-программирование, phpstorm, ftp, owl-carousel

На сайт выводится owl-carousel, её нужно править, а найти где она не получается. Пользуюсь phpStorm, с сайтом работаю через ftp сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в ваших директориях со стилями (css) и скриптами (js) файлы указанные на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если таких файлов нет, значит они подключаются через CDN

В этом случае править их не получиться, а необходимо их непосредственно скачать и подключить с файловой системы